# How to repair missing GPG public keys for packages

Tags: apt, updates, virtualbox, gnupg, coreutils

Earlier today I was removing VirtualBox, and when removing its public key, I accidentally instead of putting the key ID, put the fingerprint:

```
sudo apt-key del 7B0F AB3A 13B9 0743 5925  D9C9 5442 2A4B 98AB 5139
```

The output as usual was:

```
OK
```

And now (although they could be completely unrelated) coreutils' public key is missing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Need to get 12.7 MB of source archives.
Get:1 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid/main coreutils 8.23-3ubuntu1 (dsc) [1,414 B]
Get:2 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid/main coreutils 8.23-3ubuntu1 (tar) [12.6 MB]
Get:3 gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid/main coreutils 8.23-3ubuntu1 (diff) [114 kB]
Fetched 12.7 MB in 16s (751 kB/s)
gpgv: Signature made Mon 03 Nov 2014 07:34:45 GMT using DSA key ID 5662C734
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
dpkg-source: warning: failed to verify signature on ./coreutils_8.23-3ubuntu1.dsc
dpkg-source: info: extracting coreutils in coreutils-8.23
dpkg-source: info: unpacking coreutils_8.23.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying coreutils_8.23-3ubuntu1.diff.gz
```

Are these two things related, and if so, how do I reinstall the missing public keys which I would have accidentally removed, and how do I tell which were removed? Is there some sort of key ID search?
However, if the two are not related, why is my public key for coreutils missing, and how do I get it back?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
coreutils:
  Installed: 8.23-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 8.23-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 8.23-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I think part of the problem was you didn't use quotes, and `apt-key` (well, `gpg`) interpreted those as multiple keys. Can you run `sudo apt-get update` to see all the keys you're missing? (Also, technically, it's not `coreutils`'s public key; it's the key to the main Ubuntu archive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webupd8team has created a very good program for fixing PPAs and just general PPA management.

To install the tool run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Then run it with:

```
sudo y-ppa-manager
```

Go to the the `Advanced` section:

[image]

And then run `Try to import all missing GPG keys`:

[image]

This may take a while, but it will alert you when done.

More information about webupd8 can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda It looks good!  Thanks for the edit!  =)