# open jdk install error

Tags: openjdk

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h', which is also in package openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install java 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759413/unable-to-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-32-bit) , have you tried this : http://askubuntu.com/a/759454/476968 ? I can see you are working on Jdk9 but that is basically the same problem as that on the link above, i think.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-9-jdk-headless`?